# Woocommerce - Show cart even if it's empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

My WordPresss related task is simple, but I can't find the solution. I have 2 products in my woocommerce shop, and I would like to show both of them on the cart-page in the woocommerce table, let the customer set the quantity of them. If the customer don't want to buy something, just leave it on 0.

The problem is the cart table is not shown if it is empty and I can only see the items that I put in there.

Answer (score 0):

you can add product like that and add condition according you i set for admin and product id. change product id with your product id

```
/*
 * goes in theme functions.php or a custom plugin
 **/
// add item to cart on visit
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $product_id = 64;
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```